# Load library from MemoryClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader

I've been working on a sort of bootstrapper for an application I am writing. It buffers an application from a website and runs it. It works very well up to the point that I call the main method of the main class of the application, which requires libraries, which are also streamed. The LIBs and the Application are in the same classloader, but it says it was unable to locate the library due to an unsatisfied link. I searched for help, but could not find any.

Comment: Unless you provide the exact error message and perhaps some of your loader code, the only thing we can see wrong is that double `m` in `MemmoryClassLoader`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` because you haven't done a `Runtime.loadLibrary` to bring in native code to support `native` methods.  Such libraries need to be on the local file-system and are independent of any class loader.  Javadoc:

> ```
> public void loadLibrary(String libname)
> ```
>
> Loads the dynamic library with the specified library name. A file containing native code is loaded **from the local file system** from a place where library files are conventionally obtained. **The details of this process are implementation-dependent**. The mapping from a library name to a specific filename is done in a system-specific manner.

and obviously, `Runtime.getRuntime()` is independent of any particular class loader.

If a network class load could cause a network load of native code, that would be a huge [remote code execution vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) because native code cannot be constrained by a `SecurityManager` the way java bytecode can be.

If you trust the website that produces the application, and are fetching it over a secure channel (encrypted to prevent MITM and tampering), then you can fetch the libraries, dump them to the local file system, verify any signatures or checksums, then call [`Runtime.loadLibrary` or `System.loadLibrary`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) to load the native libraries before causing the class to initialize.

If you don't trust the authors of the website that produces the application, or that website hosts third-party content, then don't load JARs much less system libraries from it.

Even if the website authors are trustworthy, loading system libraries or other native code that you haven't vetted and tested can be dangerous.  Process sandboxing via `chroot` and system call interception can help mitigate this risk somewhat but be careful.

Comment: I am trying to load a library jar from my domain, these aren't necessarily system libraries.

Comment: @RomanHargrave, If you're getting an [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html), then they are system libraries.  Are you getting that or a different kind of `LinkageError`?

Comment: It looks like the problem is a no biggie. I just realized the issue had to do with the error messages LWJGL likes to throw. I'll get back to you on that!

Comment: @RomanHargrave, Editing your post to include the error messages would help me and others on SO to diagnose your problem.

Comment: It looks like the problem was just a misinterpreted error message, which is what was confusing me. All i have left here it seems is to add ClassLoader.getResource() functionality.